# Unmarshal namespaced XML tags - Golang

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to extract metadata from an `.odt` document.

The file containing XML is called `meta.xml`

It has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" office:version="1.2">
    <office:meta>
        <meta:creation-date>2016-10-18T15:05:19.137453293</meta:creation-date>
        <dc:title>Document</dc:title>
        <dc:date>2017-01-17T00:59:04.731054728</dc:date>
        <meta:document-statistic meta:page-count="1" meta:word-count="0" meta:character-count="0"/>
    </office:meta>
</office:document-meta>
```

I'm using `xml.Unmarshal()` from the `encoding/xml` package to parse the XML and place the values inside struct fields.

This is the struct I'm using:

```
type Query struct {
    CreationDate string `xml:""`
    PageCount int `xml:""`
    WordCount int `xml:""`
    CharCount int `xml:""`
}
```

What I understood from the available documentation is that I can use field tags of type `xml:"tag-name"` to get the value of the XML tag, and `xml:name,attr` to get the attribute value.

However, since the XML file has namespaced tags (e.g. `meta:creation-date`) everything I've tried so far leaves the struct fields empty. Although, I might be doing something wrong.

This is the entire program inside Go playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/n7C50l1gsV

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519 -- last comment suggests that only prefixed attributes (not elements) are supported.

Comment: How would I go about extracting just the prefixed attributes? Example: `meta:word-count="0"` or are they also not accessible because the tag is name-spaced?

Comment: Here's an updated version of your playground [code](https://play.golang.org/p/YFO5jp70gN) that may help.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring It does indeed work. Thanks. Do you mind elaborating what I was doing wrong? Does the struct layout have to correspond to the tag layout?

Comment: In theory you can skip into sub-elements with `>`, but it's definitely easier to reason about the unmarshalling when it fairly directly maps to the structs.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring Great, seems like it was just a newbie mistake. Do you mind posting the code from playground as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find that things go more smoothly if your structs map fairly directly to the XML. This code should get you started:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Stats struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name
    PageCount int `xml:"page-count,attr"`
}

type Meta struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Date    string `xml:"creation-date"`
    Title   string `xml:"title"`
    Stats   Stats  `xml:"document-statistic"`
}

type DocumentMeta struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Meta    Meta `xml:"meta"`
}

var data = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-meta>
    <office:meta>
        <meta:creation-date>2016-10-18T15:05:19.137453293</meta:creation-date>
        <dc:title>Document</dc:title>
        <dc:date>2017-01-17T00:59:04.731054728</dc:date>
        <meta:document-statistic meta:page-count="1" meta:word-count="0" meta:character-count="0"/>
    </office:meta>
</office:document-meta>`)

func main() {
    var dm DocumentMeta
    xml.Unmarshal(data, &dm)
    fmt.Println(dm)
}
```